# Some Services Not Able To Constructed .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

How Can I Solve This?

My Error Message

`System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Identity.Models.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Identity.Models.AppUser,Identity.Models.AppRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Identity.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Identity.Models.AppRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Identity.Models.AppRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Identity.Models.AppRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Identity.Models.AppRole]'.)'

Db Context

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Identity.Models
{
    public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string>
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=DESKTOP-B64E139;database=IDENTITYDB;integrated security=true");
        }
    }
}
```

Program cs

```
    using Identity.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```